# Unknown user permission: ManageSandboxes

Tags: metadata, ant, migration

Using the Force.com Migration Tool (Ant) v1.9.4 to deploy from one sandbox to another both on Spring '17 results in

```
21.  profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ManageSandboxes
22.  profiles/Finance.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ManageTranslation
23.  profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: SocialInsightsLogoAdmin
etc.
```

If the orgs are on the same release, how is the target returning an error here?
I'm guessing there are manual settings that are different from org-to-org?

This is such a common error it makes using the Ant tool frustrating

Answer (score 5):

My source and target environment were on the same version so to solve similar issue I clicked "Match Production Licenses" on source and target. Please verify.

Comment: If you’re using CI, this could be a common solution to avoid manual steps.

Comment: hello i have tried this and i clicked from both source and target org but still got the same error - Error: Unknown user permission: ManageSandboxes  , any solution please

Answer (score 2):

There are permissions that vary from org to org, either because of permissions provided by Salesforce, or features that can be enabled by an administrator. If a particular feature is not enabled, the related profile permissions will also not exist, which will cause errors like this. For example, deploying a profile to a sandbox, you'll notice that ManageSandboxes does not exist, because Sandboxes cannot create other Sandboxes. Similarly, if Translation Workbench is not enabled in an org, the ManageTranslations permission will not exist. Make sure that the destination org has the same licenses and features as the source organization, or you will need to manually edit your profile files to remove the missing permissions.

Comment: Can you elaborate why ManageSandboxes in not available under UserPermissions. For me, ManageSandboxes in not available in Full Sandbox, but it is available in Partial Sandbox.

Comment: @IsuruBuddhikaHerath I'm not sure. That sounds like a glitch. When I wrote this answer, you couldn't access the Sandbox menu at all in a sandbox, so the permission also didn't exist (or I was mistaken?). Have you tried contacting Support?

Comment: If you search on setup, you cannot find the sandboxes menu. That is correct. But in my case, when I go to, `Setup -> Profiles -> System Administrator -> System Permissions`. The `ManageSandboxes` permission was not availble under the `Users` section at the bottom of the page. Any way I was able to fix this pressing `Setup -> Company Information -> Match Production Lcienses`.

Answer (score 2):

Unknown user permission errors are because you have not activated a feature in the target org.

When you activate a different features, Salesforce creates new settings/options.

ManageSandboxes is a setting in production, matching licenses should fix this issue.

ManageTranslation - you have to activate Transaltions in the target org. Setup > transaltions > Enable

SocialInsightsLogoAdmin - not sure, but im assuming its something with a feature called Social Insights.

Answer (score 0):

The "unknown user permission" type errors are either because of-

- The version indicated in the package.xml doesn't support the feature, or
- The source environment is on a newer API version than the target, and it's supported in the former and not the latter, which is not valid in your case.

So I guess it is because of the version in your package.xml

Try to make sure **your source and target environment will be on the same version** whenever you plan to deploy.

If this is no longer possible, you can also manually remove the reference to that specific profile permission before deploying.

Comment: These are the boilerplate answers for sure. Both orgs are Spring '17 and I'm using v.39 so I'm baffled as to why I have to manually edit in this instance.  I've been unable to find docs on which permissions API v.39 supports although I sure thought it was after these features were released.